# The declared package test does not match the expected package

Tags: java, class, package

So, I have this code:

```
package test;
import test.Pi;
public class Demo {
    public static int pi = 3;   
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        Pi.main(args);
        System.out.println("Hello again!");
    }
}
```

But eclipse keeps throwing up an error at the very first line, saying "The declared package test does not match the expected package".
Any help apreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a matter of *importing* - that means you're trying to *declare* that the package for this class (`Demo`) is `test`, but the compiler error shows that you've got it in the wrong place - you've got it in the root of your source path, instead of in a directory called `test` under the source root.

Three possible changes:

- Don't put it in the `test` package; given the title of your question, it's not clear whether you were trying to do that or not. You don't need to import any classes which are in the same package as the class you're declaring.
- Move `Demo.java` into a `test` folder if it's not already.
- If `Demo.java` *is* already in a `test` folder, change your build configuration so that its *parent* directory is the source root.

Comment: I should probably clarify-- I'm trying to reference a class in a different package by using the import function.

Comment: @user1470896: but you're not in a different package, the package declaration says 'package test;'

Comment: @user1470896: But it's not the import which is causing the error - as you said yourself, the error is on the very first line, which is a `package` declaration.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a bit thick, but I'm trying to access it from a different package. So, for instance, package1/Demo.java is trying to access test/Pi.java

Comment: @Cowthulhu: You seem to be missing what we're saying - look at your code. You have `package test;` as the first line. That's not trying to *access* a package - that's declaring that the `Demo` class *is* in the `test` package. At that point `test.Pi` is in the same package. It sounds like you should have a package declaration of `package package1;`

Comment: Ahh, I see. So, I've change it to say `package package1;`. That seems to work. Exept, now, the _second_ line isn't working, the one doing the importing.

Comment: @Cowthulhu: Then I suggest you ask a new question giving *details* about what's happening... including what your `Pi` class looks like.

Answer (score 0):

**-** The error which you have received says that you are using the wrong package name.

**-** Please see, **are you in the test directory or not.**

**-** And please remove the **`** before your package name.