# VS Code: The declared package "controller" does not match the expected package ""

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

So, I have checked some other threads that are about this topic, such as the following:

[Eclipse says package declaration does not match expected package ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773385/eclipse-says-package-declaration-does-not-match-expected-package)

[The declared package test does not match the expected package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823710/the-declared-package-test-does-not-match-the-expected-package)

[libgdx: The declared package does not match the expected package ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894698/libgdx-the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package)

But they all deal with Eclipse (or Eclipse + Maven), and I am just using VS Code without all the fancy capabilities of an IDE or a package manager.

As the title suggests, I am getting the message:
[Java] The declared package "controller" does not match the expected package ""

I get this message for every single file that I attempt to give a package using the syntax:

`package myPackageName;`

even if the file in question is defiantly in the right folder. This problem only occurs as a visual, i.e. everything compiles fine using javac. I have been dealing with it ever since I started using VS Code for my Java Projects.

**How do I make the red squigglies and the red lettering in the file explore tab go away in the case of perceived package errors??** It drives me nutty, I can't quickly find the files that actually have errors in my project because everything is marked red except the Driver.

Here is a picture: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7nzN.png)

[edit] Got rid of the unrelated compile time errors So you can see it compiles.

Comment: The actual error says "MainController is not abstract". Ignore the red squiggle and fix the reported errors.

Comment: Ignore my compile time errors at the bottom. These are unique to the project I am working on, and I know for a fact have nothing to do with the annoying red squigglies on my package declarations based on previous experience with the problem. (The errors a clearly JavaFx issues).

Comment: There, I updated the picture

Comment: Don't post pictures like that. But fine. What does it say under "PROBLEMS (4)" tab?

Comment: https://imgur.com/m8R62LS

Comment: I believe you need some kind of project file so vscode actually knows what to build.

Answer (score 2):

All classes in the package should be open on VSCode (on different tabs).
Same thing happens when you want to use other public classes in same directory: it should be visible but when you run the program, you will get a compile-time error. Then again the solution is to have all classes open on different tabs.
Hope it helps

Comment: Given that the problems are listed for all files it finds, even if they were never open in the editor yet, I really don't see how it could help.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to it, but here is my finding:

Your parent folder is `proto9`, so in all your child folders, i.e. `controller`, `model` and `view`. You should write `package proto9.controller`, `package proto9.model` etc. You can compile the `.java` file just fine in the correct directory, but not 100% sure why we cannot run it while in the directory of the file is at, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is returned  when attempted so.

To successfully run it, in the terminal (assuming your files **are compiled**):

`# cd one level out of your parent directory`

`PS C:\Users\Issac\Dropbox\Apps\Celerious Text\proto9> cd ..`

`PS C:\Users\Issac\Dropbox\Apps\Celerious Text> java proto9.controller.MainController`

`...`

`PS C:\Users\Issac\Dropbox\Apps\Celerious Text> java proto9.view.MainView`

etc.

Hope this works for you as well!!

Comment: The `proto9` is the project directory. That's where the paths are rooted. And if that was the problem, the error should be saying “declared package "controller" does not match the expected package "proto9.controller"”. But it says “package ""”. That clearly shows something does not have a clue where the project is actually rooted.